# How to convert from Array to Hashmap

Tags: for-loop, clojure, hashmap

I have a string:

```
{:id 1, :name "Ab Bc Cd", :sex "M", :birth "01.01.1999", :address "Street 1", :oms "0001"}
```

And i need to convert it to HashMap but

```
(hash-map my-str)
```

returns {}
So i splited it:

```
(s/split my-str ",")
```

And it returns

```
[:id 1  :name "Ab Bc Cd"  :sex "M"  :birth "01.01.1999"  :address "Street 1"  :oms "0001"]
```

Then

```
for [x my-arr]
(hash-map x)
```

returns

```
({} {} {} {} {} {})
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you got this string intentionally, then use

[`clojure.edn/read-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string)

E.g.

```
user=> (require 'clojure.edn)
nil
user=> (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "x.edn"))
{:id 1, :name "Ab Bc Cd", :sex "M", :birth "01.01.1999", :address "Street 1", :oms "0001"}
```

Comment: note the clojure.edn in that recommendation, that's the safe and proper way for trusted input. clojure.core/read-string will in some cases run arbitrary cuddle passed in the input. I have found this in public sites out there on the internet (with permission) so remember to put that clojure.edn

Answer (score 2):

your example is almost there!

you can finish it with a call to

```
(into {} your-result-so-far)
```

into comes up a lot of you get into the habit of looking for it.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, since `(str/split s #",")` should yield a result like `["{:id 1" ...]`

Comment: @AlanThompson "result-so-far" would be the result of OPs `for` (which lacks some parens)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way would be `clojure.core`'s `read-string` - it `read`s from the string and executes the command for building an object:

```
(def s "{:id 1, :name \"Ab Bc Cd\", :sex \"M\", :birth \"01.01.1999\", :address \"Street 1\", :oms \"0001\"}")
(read-string s)
;; => {:id 1, :name "Ab Bc Cd", :sex "M", :birth "01.01.1999", :address "Street 1", :oms "0001"}
```

The documentation says:

> Reads one object from the string s. Optionally
> include reader options, as specified in read.  Note that read-string
> can execute code (controlled by *read-eval*), and as such should be
> used only with trusted sources.  For data structure interop use
> clojure.edn/read-string